# Semicolon before (()=>true)()

Tags: javascript

It works fine:

```
const foo = 1; // any number, string, bolean or object
(() => console.log('stuff'))()
```

But it doesn't work without semicolon:

```
const foo = 1 // TypeError: 1 is not a function
(() => console.log('stuff'))()
```

Hm...
Should not the call of an anonymous function be treated as *a separate instruction* in the case *when the first bracket can not be interpreted as a correct continuation of the previous instruction*?

Comment: The parser just ignores whitespaces and new lines, so your code is to the parser: `const foo = 1(() => console.log('stuff'))()`. Looks familiar?

Comment: The interpreter sees `1` as a curried function: `1(...)()`.

Comment: Without the semicolon you are calling `1` as a function with as argument a function. `1(() => console.log('stuff'))`. The interpreter is placing everything at one line. This is one of the use cases for why the semicolon is in the language. And for why you should use it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's only about *syntactically correct* continuations.

```
1(() => console.log('stuff'))()
```

is a syntactically correct expression and parses as "call `1` with an argument of `() => console.log('stuff')`, then call the result of that without arguments". This throws an exception at runtime (`1` is not function, so it can't be called), but it's still a valid expression.

Answer (score 1):

You should alway use semicolons. If you do not add them, Javascript will guess where to insert them and will lead to errors.

In your case, it is interpreting that you are calling a function.

A good article on the topic on [how semicolons are automatically inserted](http://2ality.com/2011/05/semicolon-insertion.html):

> The norm: The parser treats every new token as part of the current
>   statement, unless there is a semicolon that terminates it. The
>   following examples show code where you might think a semicolon should
>   be inserted, but isn’t. This illustrates the risks of omitting
>   semicolons.
>
> No ASI:
>
> ```
> a = b + c
> (d + e).print()
> ```
>
> This does not trigger ASI, because the opening parenthesis could follow c in a function call. The above is thus
>   interpreted as:
>
> ```
> a = b + c(d + e).print();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> …when the first bracket can not be interpreted as a correct continuation of the previous instruction?

But it can - as you can see, the code parses just fine, and executes. That it will throw a runtime exception when no semicolon isn't inserted doesn't matter to the [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572), it cannot know while parsing.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, it doesn't matter how many spaces you have, it will just be treated as one space only.

in your second code snippet, it just actually equals:

```
const foo = 1 (() => console.log('stuff'))()
```

which means you invoke a function called '1' and pass '()=>console.log('stuff')' as an argument. but apparently 1 is not a function, so it throw an error, hope make sense to you